# Error Logging in a ASP.NET WebApplication

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling, error-logging

If an exception occurs, it should be logged to a text file. And that the user should be redirected to a page that explains the error to the user.

Where do I start?

Comment: Use a try - catch block. Configure the location of file in web.config and add the file parameters with the try - catch block.

Comment: Actually, I need to log the error to a textfile.

Comment: Do you want each exception to be logged to its own unique file? Or would you prefer that all exceptions be logged to one file?

Comment: Either way it will be fine.... but i most likely prefer it be just 1 file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend using log4net.  It's very easy to get this in place.

First, [download log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/download_log4net.cgi).  Unzip this, and add a reference to log4net.dll in your project.

Create a basic config file named `log4net.config` in your root folder. This will log errors in log files named by date in the Logs folder outside of your web root.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log4net debug="false">
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />
        <param name="File" value="..\\Logs\\" />
        <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
        <param name="MaxSizeRollBackups" value="30" />
        <param name="MaximumFileSize" value="100MB" />
        <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date" />
        <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="false" />
        <param name="CountDirection" value="-1" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n" />
        </layout>
        <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
            <threshold value="DEBUG" />
        </evaluator>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

In the `Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs` file, add the following line.  This will automatically configure log4net from the configuration file when your application is started.

```
[assembly: XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "./Log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

To catch errors and log them, you'll need to add the following to `Global.asax.cs`

```
private static readonly ILog m_Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the error
    Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();

    // Log the error to a text file
    m_Logger.Fatal("Unhandled application error", exception);

    // Redirect to error page
    Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
}
```

There are a few steps involved in getting this working, but they're all fairly easy to do, and once log4net is in place, you can easily add logging elsewhere in your application (instead of just logging unhandled exceptions).

Comment: Was going to recommend the very thing however was not sure if he was looking for something as simple as creating a unique text file for every exception or something as simple as File.Write

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at ELMAH - http://code.google.com/p/elmah/ - if you're looking for a solution that will perform part of this (the logging).

Looking into using custom errors in your application for the other part. For example, [ASP.net Custom Errors Loggin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036436/asp-net-custom-errors-loggin)

Comment: Actually, I dont see the need of a third-party app when you can do this in asp.net

Comment: Actually, I see the teensiest of a contradiction starting between 'not needing an external component' and 'asking how best to do something'.

Comment: You can do a ton of things in ASP.NET, without the use of third-party apps, but do you really want to re-invent the wheel? Also, the suggestions for log4net are fine as well. I've found ELMAH to be referenced far more (and the last time I checked log4net was a bit large for what my projects require), so I've stuck with it.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Patterns and Practices Team has developed an group of application blocks which solve common problems when building .net applications, called Enterprise Library.  They have a block for logging called the Logging Application Block.  There is another block for encapsulating your exception handling called the Exception Handling block.

I would recommend looking at the Logging Application block for handling your logging.

[Enterprise Library 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650810.aspx)