# In asp.NET using C# can I create an error log?

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling

I have a C#.net site which displays custom error pages to the user. This is set in web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="Off">
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/error.cshtml" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error.cshtml" />
</customErrors>
```

The problem is that if there is an error, I have no record of what it was. I'm familiar with PHP where I can set a location for the error_log file which I can then check for PHP errors. Is there a way to do something similar in .NET?

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-use-Apache-log4net-0d969339

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Logging in a ASP.NET WebApplication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531859/error-logging-in-a-asp-net-webapplication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use log4net dll, it has provisions to log errors as well as diagnostic messages.

Link where the log4net is available :

https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/example-apps.html

Codeproject demo to get started :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8245/A-Brief-Introduction-to-the-log-net-logging-librar

Answer (score 0):

You can try [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/). Here is a [Tutorial](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in logging functionality that comes with ASP.NET.

Set it up in system.diagnostics in web.config, declare a trace source in your code and off you go.

You can configure it to write to the event log as well as log files and custom destinations.

I just did a quick google search and found an introductory article here: http://www.thejoyofcode.com/from_zero_to_logging_with_system_diagnostics_in_15_minutes.aspx

You will find many more without too much effort.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the HealthMonitoring possibilities that come with ASP.Net. For instance, you can get references to exceptions and send emails with the exception to a specified address. A couple of years ago I wrote this article about HealthMonitoring: http://www.tomot.de/en-us/article/6/asp.net/how-to-create-a-custom-healthmonitoring-provider-that-sends-e-mails

If you want a more mature error logging solution, have a look at *Elmah*.